# Python multiple MySQL queries

Tags: python, mysql

I'm creating a Discord bot for my channel.

```
def getPSN(id):
    query = ("SELECT psn FROM users WHERE id = %s LIMIT 1")
    cursor.execute(query, (id,))
    psn = cursor.fetchone()[0]
    return psn


@client.command(name="reports")
async def reports():
    query = ("SELECT involved_id, reporter_id FROM stewards WHERE status = 0")
    cursor.execute(query)
    for (involved_id, reporter_id) in cursor:
        await client.say("Involved: " + getPSN(involved_id) + " Reporter: " + getPSN(reporter_id))
```

function Reports is called with !reports command in Discord chat, it then gets the open steward reports from the DB.
In the client.say I return it to chat, with converting their IDs to their names in getPSN() function.

When I try it out, it returns

> Involved: somename Reporter: somename

But there should be around 6 results. When I remove the getPSN from the client.say it returns all 6 results with the IDs instead of the names obviously.

I assume the first query is forgotten when I 'replace' it with the getPSN query or something?

I have zero experience with Python.

Comment: It seems like you use the same `cursor` in both functions. In that case, your assumption is correct. The `cursor` is some sort of a handle/container for a query and its result. Executing a subsequent query on a cursor flushes it and the previous result becomes unavailable. Using a dedicated cursor (don't forget to close it) in `getPSN` should fix this issue.

Comment: Working like a charm, thanks!